# Can’t turn on WiFi when installing CentOS Stream

Tags: centos, wifi, system-installation

This is my first post on Unix StackExchange :)

I am currently having a problem while installing CentOS Stream on my Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH laptop.

During the installation process, I cannot turn on the WiFi even though CentOS is detecting my wireless adapter. I'm using the graphical installer. The button to turn on the WiFi cannot be turned on.

Here is the command I used to check if CentOS could see it properly :

`lspci -nn | grep -i wireless`

This gives me the following information :

`Network controller (0200): Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)`

Also, the command `nmcli d` tells me that my ethernet and wifi are in an 'Unavailable' state.

Could anyone be kind enough to help me out, or point me in the right direction, regarding this problem? That would be very nice.

Thank you all and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case of `rfkill` interfering with your WLAN devices.

Try running `rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: Just blacklist the lenovo drivers with the command at this link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049129/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-lenovo-legion-y520